# Get full url of www.example.com/#cauta/abcdefg

Tags: php

I have a link like 
www.example.com/#cauta/abcdefg but no method to get full path found until now.
Tried all combination of $_SERVER.
The problem is that the hash tag # its not seen by REQUEST_URI
Thanks!

Comment: Everything behind the `#` is only handled by the browser and never sent to the server. The only way u can access this is by javascript

Comment: to add to that, that's a horrible URL structure. The internet experimented with it for the purposes of "natural reading" ajax URLs, and very quick discovered it was horrible for reasons you're discovering, as well as for then navigating to genuine fragment id locations inside the articles. (because # in a URL is a fragment ID, and treating it as a sneaky path loader breaks that HTML convention)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the hash using javascript, and send it using ajax to get processed like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
        // hash now contains "cauta/abcdefg"
        $.get("/process.php?hash=" + escape(hash), function(data){
            // append the result to the end of the body
            $("body").append(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Next process the data using PHP (we will just dump it for this example):

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET["hash"]);
```

Comment: I need to get the "abcdefg" which differs every time. I need for it to be read when url is opened by the index.php and then process the rest of the script. But everything after # is not read..

Comment: you could grab it using javascript then do an ajax request.

Comment: @CrY If this answer is what help and you used, please accept the answer so others know that this answer worked.

Answer (score 0):

The full path is http://www.example.com. The rest of the URL is used to locate a resource within the page. It is also available to any javascript on the page, which may in turn decide to render different information based on this value.

If you have Firefox or Chrome, try this: right-click anywhere on the page, click "Inspect Element", then clock on the network tab. Now reload your page. You will see all the assets that are used to generate this page. This may give you a clue as to where the data is that you desire.

Comment: Yes but javascript not usefull for me